# Swift: Updating 2d Array Issue

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

I'm working on a feature where a user can enter custom guitar tablature. What I would like to happen is a user selects a designated fret, once done so they can hold down that selected number and choose whether its a hammer on, pull off , etc. (overlay is displayed where user can select this)

What is happening is the suffix that was added is *remaining* if a new number is added. So to clarify if a user had just selected "hammer on" and an "h" is added to that number. Great -- issue is if the user adds another number to that row, the new number will keep the "h" suffix instead of just being a number with no suffix.

I would like this not to happen and only have a suffix added a user manually adds it with the overlay radio buttons.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

```
struct Tablature: View {
    //2d array to represent guitar fretboard
    @State private var numbers: [[Int?]] = [
        [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil,nil,nil,nil, nil],
        [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil,nil,nil,nil, nil],
        [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil,nil,nil,nil, nil],
        [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil,nil,nil,nil, nil],
        [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil,nil,nil,nil, nil],
        [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil,nil,nil,nil, nil],
        
                                          
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal){
            VStack(spacing: 10) {
                ForEach(0..<6) { rowIndex in
                    TabRow(rowIndex: rowIndex, numbers: $numbers)
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
       
    }
}


struct TabRow: View {
    func columnText(for rowIndex: Int) -> String {
            switch rowIndex {
            case 0:
                return "E"
            case 1:
                return "A"
            case 2:
                return "D"
            case 3:
                return "G"
            case 4:
                return "B"
            case 5:
                return "E"
            default:
                return ""
            }
        }
    
    
    func showNumberInputAlert(for rowIndex: Int, columnIndex: Int) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Enter a number", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addTextField { textField in
            textField.keyboardType = .numberPad
        }
        
        let doneAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .default) { _ in
            if let text = alert.textFields?.first?.text, let number = Int(text) {
                numbers[rowIndex][columnIndex] = number
            }
        }
        alert.addAction(doneAction)
        
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
  
    var rowIndex: Int // << keep track of row
    @Binding var numbers: [[Int?]] // represents guitar string
    @State var showAdditionalTabFeatures = false
    @State private var selectedOption: Int = 0 // << for tab radio picker
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(columnText(for: rowIndex))
                .padding(.trailing, 10)
            
            ForEach(0..<10) { columnIndex in
                if let number = numbers[rowIndex][columnIndex] {
                    if selectedOption == 1 {
                        Text("\(number)h")
                    } else if selectedOption == 2 {
                        Text("\(number)p")
                    } else if selectedOption == 3 {
                        Text("\(number)s")
                    } else {
                        Text("\(number)")
                            .frame(width: 20, height: 2)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                showNumberInputAlert(for: rowIndex, columnIndex: columnIndex)
                            }
                            .overlay(
                               Group {
                                   if showAdditionalTabFeatures {
                                       HStack {
                                           Button(action: {
                                               selectedOption = 1
                                           }) {
                                               HStack {
                                                   Text("Hammer-On")
                                                       .font(.caption)
                                                   Image(systemName: selectedOption == 1 ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "circle")
                                                       .onTapGesture {
                                                           selectedOption = 1
                                                           showAdditionalTabFeatures = false
                                                          
                                                       }
                                               }
                                           }
                                           .fixedSize()
                                           .foregroundColor(.white)
                                           .padding(8)
                                           .background(Color.black)
                                           .cornerRadius(8)
                                          
                                           Button(action: {
                                               selectedOption = 2
                                               
                                           }) {
                                               HStack {
                                                   Text("Pull Off")
                                                       .font(.caption)
                                                   Image(systemName: selectedOption == 2 ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "circle")
                                                       .onTapGesture {
                                                           selectedOption = 2
                                                           showAdditionalTabFeatures = false
                                                          
                                                       }
                                               }
                                           }
                                           .fixedSize()
                                           .foregroundColor(.white)
                                           .padding(8)
                                           .background(Color.black)
                                           .cornerRadius(8)

                                           Button(action: {
                                               selectedOption = 3
                                           }) {
                                               HStack {
                                                   Text("Slide")
                                                       .font(.caption)
                                                   Image(systemName: selectedOption == 3 ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "circle")
                                                       .onTapGesture {
                                                           selectedOption = 3
                                                           showAdditionalTabFeatures = false
                                                          
                                                       }
                                               }
                                           }
                                           .fixedSize()
                                           .foregroundColor(.white)
                                           .padding(8)
                                           .background(Color.black)
                                           .cornerRadius(5)
                                          
                                       }
                                       .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                       .offset(y:  -50) // Adjust the position of the overlay as per your requirement
                                   }
                               }
                           )
                            .gesture(
                                LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.05)
                                    .onEnded { _ in
                                        showAdditionalTabFeatures = true
                                        print("is longpressing")
                                    }
                            )
                    }
                }
                else {
                    Rectangle()
                        .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2, dash: [100]))
                        .frame(width: 20, height: 2)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            showNumberInputAlert(for: rowIndex, columnIndex: columnIndex)
                          
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```